# generic ? abstract class ? what's the best to design my code?

Tags: .net, generics, collections, virtual, abstract

```
  class TypeA 
  {
      public TypeA Copy () { ... }
      public bool IsEqual(TypeA mytypeA) { ... }
      public bool IsSame(TypeA mytypeA) { ... }
      ...
  }

  class TypeACollection : List<TypeA>
  {
      public bool IsSame (TypeACollection typeAs)
      {
          if (Count != typeAs.Count) 
              return false;
          return this[0].IsSame(typeAs[0]);
      }
      ...
  }
```

TypeB, TypeC have the similiar funcions Copy/IsEqual/IsSame as TypeA.
  TypeBCollection, TypeACollection have the similiar IsSame. The exception is TypeBCollection use TypeB.IsSame, TypeCCollection use TypeC.IsSame.

now, I plan to add 2 new classes: LocData and LocDataCollection

```
class LocData 
{
    public virtual TypeA Copy () { ... }
    public virtual bool IsEqual(TypeA mytypeA) { ... }
    public virtual bool IsSame(TypeA mytypeA) { ... }
    ...
}

class LocDataCollection<T> : List<LocData> where T: LocData
{
    public bool IsSame (LocDataCollection<T> typeAs)
    {
        if (Count != typeAs.Count) 
        return false;
        return this[0].IsSame(typeAs[0]);
    }
    ...
}
```

and rewrite existing code,

```
class TypeA : LocData
{
    public new TypeA Copy () { ... }
    public new bool IsEqual(TypeA mytypeA) { ... }
    public new bool IsSame(TypeA mytypeA) { ... }
    ...
}

class TypeACollection : ???
{
    ??? 
    // so I can remove IsSame here, 
    // when I call IsSame, it will use one from LocDataCollection and still call 
    // TypeA.IsSame
    ...
}
```

now I'm lost in abstract/virtual/generic/..., which is the best way?

Comment: What's the difference between `IsEqual` and `IsSame`?

Comment: You should inherit `Collection<T>`, not `List<T>`.

Comment: IsEqual check if key equal, IsSame check if content same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace `new` with `overrides`, then create a `LocDataCollection<T> : Collection<T> where T : LocData`.

Comment: 1. I change new to override, then I got error message:       'TypeA.Copy()': return type must be 'LocData' to match overridden member 'LocData.Copy()'

Comment: 2. how about TypeACollection?

Comment: 3. where I can find more info about?